# Images coming in from image folder is displaying duplicate results

Tags: php, sql, oop, phpmyadmin

images is displaying twice when they need to display once per page_title. I get one long page_title with both images together . This is the ocean must only have the ocean picture and the lion must have only its lion picture with specific title.These images must have separate page_title.

```
      $query="SELECT * FROM page  WHERE id='$cat'";
      $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
      confirm_query($result);
      while($cat_fetch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $page_title=$cat_fetch['page_title'];


     echo "<div class=\"contentbox-1 columns one\">";
     echo "<h3 class=\"caption-2\"><a href=\"\">  $page_title </a> </h3>";
     $directory="images/*.jpg";
     $images=glob($directory);
     foreach($images as $image){
     echo "<a href=\"\"><img src='" . $image . "' width=\"340\" height=\"252\" alt=\"\" /></a>";
     }// end foreach loop

     echo "</div>"; //end grid-content-box-1






      } // end while loop
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you've got a loop within a loop, so you're looping through the database results, then you're looping through the images with each iteration. If you're referencing an individual image for each database result, shouldn't you be using just that instead of looping through the directory?

Comment: this does not work, only one image displays then so it seems like i have to loop through but i still get the same result

Comment: Is the MySQL query definitely returning two rows? If it's returning only one then looping through all the images then both images would display under the one title.

Comment: Expanding on my original answer, the foreach loop is not specific to any particular category. For each iteration you're getting all the images within the images directory by using "images/*.jpg". If you were wanting to use a category specific image you'd need to either pass the category name through to the image or reference the image name in the database